# Try to make my SVG element rotating using 'Animated' but it doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In my react-native project, I am trying to have my spinner rotating. My spinner is a SVG component `<Spinner />`. It is like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';

function Spinner(props) {
  return (
    <Svg width={24} height={24} fill="none" {...props}>
      <Path
         ...
      />
    </Svg>
  );
}

export default Spinner;
```

Since it is a static SVG element, my plan is to create a component that can have rotating animation & apply it to any screens which needs a loading spinner. So I firstly created a `LoadingSpinner` component which is supposed to have the rotation animation with the `<Spinner />`:

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Animated, Easing} from 'react-native';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

const LoadingSpinner = () => {
  const [spinAnim, setSpinAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(spinAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ).start();
  });

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Animated.View>
        <Spinner />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoadingSpinner;
```

Then, in my screen that needs a rotating spinner I just render the `LoadingSpinner`,

```
import LoadingSpinner from '../component/LoadingSpinner'
...

const MyScreen = () => {
     ...
    return (
      <View>
         {status==='loading' ? <LoadingSpinner /> : null}
      </View>
    )

}
```

When I run my app, I can see the spinner is rendered on the screen but it is not rotating. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You are correctly calculating the value of `spinAnim` (i.e. it gradually changes from `0` to `1`), but you are not using that value anywhere.
You need to connect that calculated value to some style to see the results.

In your case, since you're working with rotation, you want the values to go from `0deg` to `360deg` instead of from `0` to `1`. That can be accomplished using the `interpolate` function.

Once you have the rotation value in degrees, you can construct a style object, which will apply that value as `transform.rotate` (see `animatedStyle` in code below).

Finally, you assign that style object to the `<Animated.View>` to connect it all:

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Animated, Easing} from 'react-native';
import Spinner from './Spinner';

const LoadingSpinner = () => {
  const [spinAnim, setSpinAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const interpolateRotation = spinAnim.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
            });
            
  const animatedStyle = {
        transform: [
          { rotate: interpolateRotation }
        ]
  }

  useEffect(() => {        
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.timing(spinAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: Easing.linear,
      })
    ).start();
  });

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
        <Spinner />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default LoadingSpinner;
```

If the object you want to rotate is not centered in the <Animated.View>, you can change the center of rotation by moving the object, rotating it and then moving it back, e.g.:

```
const animatedStyle = {
        transform: [
          { translateX: -50},
          { translateY: -50},
          { rotate: interpolateRotation },
          { translateX: 50},
          { translateY: 50},
        ],
  }
```

A quick demo of the difference that it makes: [rotated around center](https://snack.expo.io/qs92AMGy3) vs [rotated around a different point](https://snack.expo.io/1dsYywvYz).

Comment: Tired your code, however the spinner (which is a circle) is not rotating around its center. Could you please update your answer to make it rotating around its center?

Comment: OK, I tried again, it was my layout style caused the rotation not in the center. I fixed that. Now it is working nicely on Android but on iOS, it rotates and gradually slow down after each rotation & eventually the spinner stops rotating. Do you know why?